# Is reinterpret_cast from Derived<X> to Base<X> safe?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, derived-class

Consider following template classes.

```
template <typename X>
class Base
{
public:
    void method1() {...}
    void method2() {...}
    ...

private:
    int  member1;
    float member2;
    ...
};

template <typename X>
class Derived : public Base<X>
{
public:
    void m1() {...}
    void m2() {...}
// no members here
}

// similar with second set of classes SecBase, SecDerived

Base<SecBase<X>> originalObject;
Derived<SecDerived<X>>& wrapperRef = reinterpret_cast<Derived<SecDerived<X>>&>(originalObject);
```

These two classes has exactly the same members. `Derived` is something like a wrapper around `Base`. Is the cast in last line safe? What if we consider compiling with optimizations? Could compiler do some optimizations that it won't work?

Comment: Is `Derived` inherited from `Base`? In your code it is not. You say that `Derived` has exactly the same members, but in your code it does not. Fix your code.

Comment: "These two classes has exactly the same members" - but they don't.

Comment: This is highly dependent on what code is generated by the complier. This looks like a bad idea. If Derived is a wrapper around Base, as you say, then why not make it a container of Base? I am confused about the sort of requirement(s) that would force you to resort to this hackery.

Comment: If `Derived` is derived from `Base`, then the conversion is safe and doesn't need a cast: `Base<X> & b = d;`. If it isn't, then they *don't* have the same members (since `Derived` is empty), so of course it's not safe. (If `Derived` *contains* a `Base` as its only member, or members identical to those of `Base`, then it *might* be safe if the classes have standard layout; but you're on shaky ground.)

Comment: Is the purpose of this question exploration of the language/compiler behavior? If it tries to solve a real problem, a different design might work better.

Comment: Sorry, my example was not complete. Please look at the latest version. It's a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: There is a catch for multiple inheritance (and maybe virtual inheritance?).  In those cases, the conversion without a cast is valid, but a `retinerpret_cast` is invalid.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Indeed, but that's got nothing to do with the question (still less, now it's been modified so implicit conversion isn't possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the cast in last line safe?

The cast is valid if the two classes are *layout-compatible*; that is

- they both have *standard layout*, as defined in C++11 9/7
- they both have the same non-static data members

It looks like the first condition is met; the second will be if none of the data member types depends on the template parameter (or, if it does, it resolves to the same type for both `SecBase<X>` and `SecDerived<X>`).

Having said that, I wouldn't describe it as "safe", since it would be easy to modify the code and accidentally break one of these conditions.

> What if we consider compiling with optimizations? Could compiler do some optimizations that it won't work?

If they're not layout-compatible, then the program has undefined behaviour and you can't rely on anything. The behaviour could change depending on optimisation or other settings, or on the phase of the moon.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, you are right about the type inside reinterpret_cast. The example code was wrong second time. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should redesign your solution for this, something like:

```
template <typename X>
class Derived
{
    Base* pB_;
public:
    Derived(Base * pB) : pB_(pB) {}
    void m1() {pB_->method1()}
    void m2() {pB_->method2()}
}
```

Comment: It's UB, unless they're standard layout types with compatible members. The question implies that that is the case.

Comment: @PaulEvans you added pointer to `Base` into `Derived` and then casting from `Derived` to `Base` will be safe? Are you sure?